# How to dynamically linking sapi.dll and making it work?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, com, speech-synthesis

I would like to dynamically bind into windows sapi.dll
and then call some code needed to 'speak' some text 
on windows - some code like this below 
(this snippet is copied from  gamedev.net article by desmond lang) 
I have no experience in using dll's especialy com. Could someone 
tell me how this code should look like to work for my? much tnx

```
   // The voice interface pointer 
   IspVoice* Voice = NULL; 

   // Initialize COM 
   CoInitialize ( NULL ); 

   // Create the voice instance 
   CoCreateInstance ( CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void**)&Voice ); 

   // Our text to be spoken 
   WCHAR* TextBuffer = "Hello World"; 

   // Use our voice interface to speak the contents of the buffer 
   Voice -> Speak ( TextBuffer, SPF_DEFAULT, NULL );
```

Comment: The question is not much clear to provide solution. Do you want to dynamically link Sapi.dll and use some exported functions from that dll ?

Comment: What happened when you ran the code?

Comment: SAPI is a COM server.  You *always* dynamically load such a server, there isn't any other way to use them.  CoCreateInstance() gets the job done.  So you never actually *link* such a server.

Comment: the problem is i have got no adequate lib file to link it static like way - I would like to do it with GeTprocAdress or something like that